# Should I say "Using support" or "Using supported" Android version?

Tags: grammar

Should I say "**Using support** Android version: *You can do something*" or "**Using supported** Android version: *You can do something*" ?

I want to mean if you have the current version, you can do *this thing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *range* of system versions is typically supported by a developer, otherwise either the market is limited, or people are forced to upgrade with every new version.

So for example you can say

> Using supported Android versions, you can do XXX.

or

> Using supported versions of Android, you can do XXX.

or

> You can do XXX using supported versions of Android.

There are currently three supported Android versions: **Nougat**, **Oreo** and **Pie**. There is a beta release of the next **Android Q** version, so to say "current version" isn't very specific.